# How % works in Python

Tags: python, percentage

I have searched but it looks like this is almost too basic to have been posted prior to this. I am starting to learn Python and I have been given an example to write. One thing I don't understand about it is how the % works in this specific example below:

```
print 3 + 2 + 1 - 5 + 4 % 2 - 1 / 4 + 6
```

I have used basic order of operations to break it down a little bit

```
(3 + 2 + 1 - 5) + (4 % 2) - (1 / 4) + 6
       1        + (4 % 2) -   .25   + 6
       1        + (4 % 2) -      6.25
```

Where I am stuck at is how (4 % 2) works. Reading the example further on the final result is 7 but I am not seeing how it comes to this. I think the issue is how I am reading it in my head. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See also https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations

Comment: Damn it , i framed such a nice answer to find out that the question is marked duplicate

Comment: @MohitBhasi then in the future, search for dupes for questions that will obviously already have answers.

Comment: @tristan should have posted a small answer then edited to a proper one :P

Comment: @MohitBhasi oh, you wanted cheap reputation that you could burn for fuel to heat your house, I understand now.

Comment: @tristan lol , strong words

Comment: Also, if you are just learning Python, I seriously suggest you learn Python 3, as it has fewer "magic" and unexpected things. (The 1/4 will give 0.25 and not 0 there).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check `1/4` you'll get 0, not 0.25. Because `1` and `4` are ints.

```
In [42]: 1/4
Out[42]: 0

In [43]: 1.0/4
Out[43]: 0.25
```

so

```
(3 + 2 + 1 - 5) = 1
(4 % 2) = 0
(1 / 4) = 0
```

and the final result will be

```
1 + 0 + 0 + 6 = 7
```

Comment: Thank you Roman, that make a lot more sense than just pointing to the modulo explanation like the people that marked it as a duplicate. Didn't realize they were considered ints so that anything other than a whole number would be considered. 

So (4 % 2) is basically written out saying (4 goes into 2) = 0 times. 
So (3 % 11) would actually be 3? 3/11 = 0
3 - 0 = 3 Right?

Comment: No, not 4 goes into to.  2 goes into 4 with 0 remainder.  The modulus of division is the integer remainder

Comment: @BrianStoiber yes, you can also check function `divmod(x, y)` which will return you a tuple `(quotient, remainder)`. So `divmod(5,2) = (2, 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

The `%` i.e modulo operator gives the remainder of the  division.

e.g.

```
>>> 5%3
2
>>> 15%3
0
>>>
```

---

The `/` division operator works like:

Integer value divided by integer value give an integer not float(1/4 = 0.25)

```
>>> 1/4
0
>>> 1.0/4
0.25
>>> 1/4.0
0.25
>>> 1.0/4.0
0.25
>>>
```

Comment: That explains the ints. Thank you. It has been about 10 years since C++ 101 back in college and just trying to learn something new.